# Button like ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an application of restaurants, each restaurant has a rating I need to increase the rating when I click on the button, but if the same person clicked on it, then decrease it again. In other words, the "I like" button
Rating I get `this.rating = this.apiService.getRestaurants().rating;`  restaurants      `this.items = this.apiService.getRestaurants ();`

`like (items) {
    items.rating ++;
}`  = rating increase

Rating variable is taken from the mysql database, backend laravel
html

```html
<div>
  <button ion-button round (tap) = "like (item)" outline ios = "ios-heart" md = "md-heart">
    <ion-icon name = "heart"> </ ion-icon>
  {{item.rating}}
  </ button> </ div>
```

How do I change the number in the database and immediately show him the increase
Help

Comment: You need to store in db not just the counter but who liked it. Basically on your server likedCounter = [ userA, userB, userF ].length is the counter. When some one likes restaurant their id is added etc.

Comment: Great idea) I can use user.id please tell me how I can add them to the database (and how best to do it), I practically novice how to receive data from the server I learned but I did not understand how to send but did not find it on the Internet resources